# Offset for variadic template integer sequence

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14

Ok, i'll try to keep this short. I know you can generate an integer sequence for variadic templates with `std::index_sequence_for`. Now suppose i want that index sequence to start at a specific offset, but still be the same length as the variadic template argument list. Is that possible? I didn't find anything of the sort on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence).

Comment: Just add the offset during expansion.

Comment: @ildjarn. well, i guess that would also be a possibility. That would force me to do a few other changes though, so if is possible to create an integer sequence within a specific range, ill do that.

Comment: What I proposed for C++14 only allows creating zero-based sequences, but it's trivial to create other sequences, see https://gitlab.com/redistd/integer_seq/blob/master/integer_seq_util.h

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You may write your own easily:

```
template <std::size_t Offset, std::size_t ... Is>
std::index_sequence<(Offset + Is)...> add_offset(std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return {};
}

template <std::size_t Offset, std::size_t N>
auto make_index_sequence_with_offset()
{
    return add_offset<Offset>(std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

[Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3992a2571ac0ee0f)